# Book about two girls who can draw portals

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I read this book a few years back and now I wanna find it again.

In the book, there're two girls who have magic powers that give them the ability to draw doors to their house. I remember that they were running from the local government at one point and I think they had a pet fox?

I'm really not sure if this is even a real book, but let me know if it sounds familiar to any of you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a lot like *[The Door to the Lost](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2374171)*, a novel from 2018 by Jaleigh Johnson.

The protagonists are two girls. They do not remember their own names, and so they call themselves Rook and Drift. Following a magic war in their own land, they are in exile in a world called Talhaven. From a review on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/36899920):

> Rook & Drift take care of each other, trading their magical skills as
> a means to survive. Their names reflect their looks & powers - Drift
> can conjure and control wind, and Rook, who has the black & white hair
> of a Rook-bird, can draw doors that lead to other worlds.
>
> Rook has been drawing doors for years as means to escape the
> constables and live on the run. But her ultimate goal is to draw the
> door that will lead her home, to the place where magic exists freely -
> and where the family she cannot remember may be waiting for her.

So only one of the girls has the ability to draw portals. The two are joined by a giant fox, unsurprisingly named Fox, who comes through one of the doors that Rook draws.